# Extend coordinate vector

Tags: matlab

I have a row vector like

```
x = [ 0.125 0.25 0.5 0.75 1];
```

And I would like to expand it to 100 points with interpolation between points. Ho can i do it so that at the end I have equally spaced points but a length of 100 points?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [something like this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/interp.html) or perhaps [like this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution

```
xi = [0     25   50  75   100];
yi = [0.125 0.25 0.5 0.75  1];

x = 1:1:100;
y = interp1(xi, yi, x);
```

Solution is y.

Explanation:

- I consider your vector [0.125 0.25 0.5 0.75 1] as the result of a function F such that F(xi) = yi where xi = [0     25    50   75    100] and yi = [0.125 0.25 0.5 0.75 1].
- I create x a 100-size vector using the same interval as xi;
- I compute the interpolation of x based on the relationship between xi and yi;